# External reference for Hyper Rayleigh Scattering at 800 nm

Tags: scattering, non-linear-optics

I'm looking for some help on the experimental part of hyper-Rayleigh scattering measurements. 
I've performed some measurements on a Nd:YAG setup at 1064 nm and used the external reference method (pNA) for determining the sample's hyperpolarizability. 
At the moment I'm working in a different setup, with a Ti:Sa laser, and want to know a good reference for this wavelength. I've only seen  papers working with internal reference for 800 nm.

Comment: I don't have personal experience with the technique, but is there a reason why the internal reference method won't work for your case?

Comment: Traditionally this method uses the solvent hyperpolarizability to calculate the solute's. The problem is the solvent signal is orders of magnitude smaller than the solutes, witch lead to bigger uncertainty. That's why I looking for an alternative.

Comment: Have you considered using any of the results of the measurements you have found in the literature as a reference for your measurement?

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility, although  some well established reference is the best option as far as I can see